# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'new_position' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

```
alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

direction = input("Type 'encode' to encrypt, type 'decode' to decrypt:\n")
text = input("Type your message:\n").lower()
shift = int(input("Type the shift number:\n"))


def caesar(direction, text, shift):
  cipher_text = ""
  for letter in text:
    if direction == "encode":
      position = alphabet.index(letter)
      new_position += position
    elif direction == "decode":
      position = alphabet.index(letter)
      new_position -= position
    cipher_text += alphabet[new_position]
  print(cipher_text)

caesar(direction, text, shift)
```

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'new_position' referenced before assignment
been trying to understand the concept of global variables but just can't figure out why there's an error occur in this code
anyone know why and how please?

Comment: The first appearance of new_position is the line new_position += position, it was not assigned a value before that. That's illegal in Python.

Comment: You never defined ```new_position```. A ```a+=1``` means ```a=a+a```. Define ```new_position``` before the loop

Comment: And can you explain what is ```shift``` for

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize `new_position` prior to the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You never set `new_position` before trying to add/subtract from it. Just add a line before the loop, like this: `new_position = 0`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is from the first `new_position += position`, you need write a `new_position = 0` before that.

Because `new_position += position` means `new_position = position + new_position`, you need give an intial value for `new_position` befor you use it